# How to configure/setup a real video wall using laptops

Tags: video, gstreamer, distributed-computing

The idea is to get a grid of laptops, say 5 x 5 for example, and play a distributed low res video across all of them simultaneously. Each laptop would act as one pixel and when the laptops are arranged in a grid people could see the video when looking at all of them together.

It would be incredible if I could somehow render this low res video on one computer and distribute it over these laptops by specifying where they fall in the grid etc...

So far I have looked into using [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) and [xinerama](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xinerama-HOWTO/intro.html) [together](http://www.linux-1u.net/X11/Quad/gstreamer.net/video-wall-howto.html) to get something like this going, but I am not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Is there a project that exists out there that can do this for me? How could I implement this myself, since it should be a little simpler being that I only want each laptop to be a single pixel? Is there a way I can test this setup without having 25 laptops handy?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the video as a whole or are they pre-splitted? It the video is whole and you don't mind decoding the video on each machine, you do just that and use videobox to crop the region. You can set a gstnetclock to sync them all to the same clock. If the video is presplitted, you just play them and again use the gstnetclock. Check the example of gstnetclock in the source repo.

Comment: Could you provide any additional information/links to videobox and gstnetclock (I want to make sure I am looking at exactly what you are referring to)

Comment: videobox: resizes a video by adding borders or cropping

Comment: netclientclock: see the api docs for it, you will basically create an instance yourself and set it on pipelines, the clocks will sync against a nettimeprovider.